# In Javascript, how do I transfer data from a text/html typed object to its parent

Tags: asp.net, javascript, object, parent

I have an

```
<object id="objPage" data="source.html" type="text/html"><object>
```

containing an HTML page, on the same domain.  I am trying to send a String through Javascript from source.html to its parent, which is an aspx page.  I need the child to be able to send that information.  Any idea?

So basically it's:

[ASPX] [OBJECT] This sends data to the ASPX [/OBJECT] This receives data from the object[/ASPX]

Comment: Your question is not very clear. You have a what?
How is the parent/child relationship established (e.g., via a frame)?

Comment: Is your question trying to send info from a usercontrol to its parent that inherited the usercontrol?

Answer (score 0):

the question isn't very clear - from what i understand you are trying to send data from JavaScript to the aspx page.

i would do this using AJAX. a simple way to do this is to use a JavaScript library such as jQuery. look here for an example of using AJAX in jQuery

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.get#urldatacallbacktype

Josh

Answer (score 0):

Without any libraries, look at XmlHttpRequest.

With something like ExtJs or similar library, You can make an Ajax.Request.